# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for Android 9 and older

Tags: android

I currently have an app running on Android 9 and I tried to not implement READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions to check behavior when accessing or opening a PDF file from the following:

- Downloads folder of my device
- Google drive (external app)
- One drive (external app)

I was just wondering why I can still access and open the PDF files from above even though I did not implement any permissions.

Based on documentation, permissions should be implemented when running on Android 9 or lower.
Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code. We have no idea what you are doing. How are you accessing? How are you opening?

Comment: In wich app are you viewing the pdf's?